# jquery checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this:

```
<div id="container1">
   <div class="block1">
      <input class="pos2" type="checkbox" /><label>Category1</label><br>
      <input class="pos3" type="checkbox" /><label>Subcategory1</label><br>
      <input class="pos3" type="checkbox" /><label>Subcategory1</label>
   </div>

   <div class="block1">
      <input class="pos2" type="checkbox" /><label>Category2</label><br>
      <input class="pos3" type="checkbox" /><label>Subcategory2</label>
      <input class="pos3" type="checkbox" /><label>Subcategory2</label>
   </div>
</container>
```

I am trying to use jquery to auto-check the checkboxes.
For example: if I would check 'pos2' it would auto-check pos3.

I used this:

```
$("#container1 .block1 .pos2").click(function(){
     $(".block1").children(".pos3").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

But I need it to only check 'pos3' from the div I clicked on.

**Note: The checkboxes are generated with PHP from entrys in a database. Their numbers can vary, thus I can't use ids on elements.**

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".pos2").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings(".pos3").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#container1 .block1 .pos2").on('change', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.pos3').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$("#container1 .block1 .pos2").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.pos3').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

in handler function `this` points to clicked object. [`.parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) will get parent of that checkbox and find will search for `.pos3` inside parent div only (like `$(".block1 .pos3")`)

Comment: @user1885099 Instead of "thank you" commenting, JFYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. And besides, BuddhiP's answer with `.siblings` is better - it is shorter and do the same thing. Plus it should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
 $("#container1 .block1 .pos2").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("div.block1:first")
     .children(".pos3").attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container1 .block1 .pos2").click(function(){
$(this).siblings(".pos3").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```